# How to insert vector of integers into Key, Value of std::map

Tags: c++, key-value, ifstream, stdvector, stdmap

**Goal:** Read numerical text files into vectors and then add the vectors to key,value `std::map` so that I can reference them by the key name I have specified for them, later.

Thought this would be easy and I am surprised that I can't find an answer for this already on StackOverflow.

**Result Expected**:

```
Print1 = {100,200,500,600}

Print2 = {7890,5678,34567,3,56}

Print3["NameA"] = Print1

Print3["NameB"] = Print2
```

If my process is inefficient or going in the wrong direction, I would appreciate the pointers.

I keep getting Semantic Issue build fails and no viable conversion from `pair <const basic_string>`

**Current Code:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

const std::string& key(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& keyValue)
{
    return keyValue.first;
}

const std::string& value(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& keyValue)
{
    return keyValue.second;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> print1;
    std::ifstream inputFile("numbers.txt");

    // test file open
    if (inputFile) 
    {
        double value; 
        // read the elements in the file into a vector
        while ( inputFile >> value ) {
            print1.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();

    std::vector<int> print2;
    std::ifstream inputFile2("numbers2.txt");

    // test file open
    if (inputFile2) 
    {
        double value;              
        // read the elements in the file into a vector
        while ( inputFile2 >> value ) {
            print2.push_back(value);
        }
    }       
    inputFile2.close();

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> contacts;   
    contacts["alice"] = print1;
    contacts["bob"] = print2;

    std::vector<std::string> keys(contacts.size());
    std::vector<int> values(contacts.size());

    transform(contacts.begin(), contacts.end(), keys.begin(), key);
    transform(contacts.begin(), contacts.end(), values.begin(), value);

    std::cout << "Keys:\n";
    copy(keys.begin(), keys.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    std::cout << "\n";

    std::cout << "Values:\n";
    copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your code doesn't compile.  Post a single line of code you're having trouble compiling, not the entire program.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't tell you which line the error occurs on, throw it away and get one that does.  But given that Xcode is a serious tool used by tons of people, I find it hard to believe it is giving you an error with no line reference.

Comment: If you can't figure out how to use your IDE to tell you the line number, just try commenting out different parts until you figure it out.

Comment: Stepped through?  Fails?  I thought you couldn't compile.  How can you step through a program which doesn't compile?  And how could it fail to compile on such a trivial line as the creation of a map?

Comment: @user3152377 what exactly, `key(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& keyValue)` and `value(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& keyValue)` in your `std::transform`? And whyt if the program failed to open the file; you will close without considering it, right?

Comment: @user3152377 if your comment that starts **it is reading as...** is your compilation error message then please edit your original post to add that text.  That will save your readers having to fish through all the comments to find that information.  I'm not familiar with Xcode but I'd guess that **2031** is your line number and **26** is your column number in the file **algorithm**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference map element directly which will create an entry if doesn't exist, and just fill it from the file read loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> m;
    int num;

    auto &&alice = m["alice"];
    std::ifstream if_alice("numbers1.txt");

    while (if_alice >> num)
        alice.push_back(num);

    if_alice.close();

    auto &&bob = m["bob"];
    std::ifstream if_bob("numbers2.txt");

    while (if_bob >> num)
        bob.push_back(num);

    if_bob.close();

    // test
    for (auto &&data : m)
    {
        std::cout << "Name: " << data.first << "\t";
        for (int num : data.second)
            std::cout << num << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and efficient! Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no point in arguing that Xcode didn't show any error msgs for your code. Try either turning on all the compiler warnings or try in online compilers. The result will be not disappointing: https://godbolt.org/z/cU54GX

---

If I have understood correctly, you want to store your information from two files(the integer values) in a `std::map`, where its key = `std::string` and value = `vector of integer array`.

If so,

**1**. You have your problem starting from reading integers from files.
    There you are using `double` for no reason and storing to
    `std::vector<int>` (i,e `print1` and `print2`).

---

**2**. Secondly, what if your file has not been open?. `inputFile.close();`
    and `inputFile2.close();` will close it anyway, without knowing the
    fact. This is wrong.
The proper way would be:

```
inputFile.open("numbers.txt", std::ios::in); // opening mode
if (inputFile.is_open()) { 
   // do stuff
   inputFile.close(); // you need closing only when file has been opened
}
```

---

**3**. If your intention is to only print `keys` and `values`, you don't
    need to parse them to different vectors.
You can do it directly:

```
for(const std::pair<kType, vType>& mapEntry: contacts)
{
    std::cout << "Key: " << mapEntry.first << "   Values: ";
    for(const int values: mapEntry.second) std::cout << values << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In c++17 you can use [Structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)

```
for(const auto& [Key, Values]: contacts)
{
    std::cout << "Key: " << Key << "   Values: ";
    for(const int value: Values) std::cout << value << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

---

**4**. If you really want to parse them to a different vector; first of all, the data structure for storing `keys` is wrong:

```
std::vector<int> values(contacts.size());
          ^^^^^^
```

which should have been a vector of vector of integers, as your `vType = std::vector<int>`. That is,

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> values
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Secondly, you have the functions `key(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& keyValue)` and `value(const std::pair<std::string, std::string>& keyValue)` wrong, where you are passing a **pair of strings** as keys and values.

This should have been

```
typedef std::string    kType;  // type of your map's key
typedef std::vector<int> vType;// value of your map's value
std::pair<kType, vType>
```

---

However, you can simply replace with lambdas, which would be more intuitive, in the sense of having the functions next to the line where you needed. For example,

```
std::vector<kType> keysVec; 
keysVec.reserve(contacts.size());
auto getOnlyKeys   = [](const std::pair<kType, vType>& mapEntry){  return mapEntry.first; };
std::transform(contacts.begin(), contacts.end(), std::back_inserter(keysVec), getOnlyKeys);
```

<kbd>**[See an example code here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HVkzPqAf6BOxdBsD)**</kbd>

Comment: I really appreciate the online compiler suggestion and pointers to where my code was failing and could be more efficient. Thanks for advancing my knowledge forward on C++.